# Vuetify 3 v-list -- prepend icon if v-list-item is active

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I'd like to prepend an icon to a v-list-item if it is active.  I can't figure out how to do this.

```html
<v-list class="px-15 pt-5" border density="compact">
  <v-list-item v-for="(item,i) in items">
    <!--  put an icon here but only if it is active? -->

    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

Can anyone guide me on how to do this in Vuetify 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<template>` tags with the slots Vuetify gives. In this case `v-list-item` has the `prepend` slot, and one of its properties is the `isActive`. You can see more here: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props-prepend

Basicaly your code would look like this:

```html
<v-list class="px-15 pt-5" border density="compact">
  <v-list-item v-for="(item,i) in items" :value="item">
    <!-- Start Slot -->
    <template v-slot:prepend="{ isActive }">
      <v-icon v-if="isActive" :icon="item.icon"></v-icon>
    </template>
    <!-- End Slot -->
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

Comment: The Vuetify 3 docs are still not great and this info isn't described there yet but `v-list-item-content` has been removed, and `v-list-item` will also require `:value="item"` for isActive to work.

Comment: Vuetify3 is pretty recent, and yeah, the docs about components are still very crude. If you are building something for production use, i higly recomend using Quasar.

Comment: Also, I've adjusted the answear, so now it should work with the `template` in the correct component, and also the obrigatory `:value`